# Custom web app authentication with WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly-9, undertow

I need to create a custom web app authentication for my Java EE application running on a WildFly 9 server. I have found few information about how to do it in [the undertow website documentation](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.2.0/index.html#adding-a-custom-authentication-mechanism).

What I have done so far is to create a `io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension` implementation:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.jboss.as.domain.http.server.security.AnonymousMechanism;
import io.undertow.security.api.AuthenticationMechanism;
import io.undertow.security.api.AuthenticationMechanismFactory;
import io.undertow.server.handlers.form.FormParserFactory;
import io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension;
import io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo;

public class MyServletExtension implements ServletExtension {

    @Override
    public void handleDeployment(DeploymentInfo deploymentInfo, ServletContext servletContext) {
        deploymentInfo.addAuthenticationMechanism("MY-AUTH", new AuthenticationMechanismFactory() {
            @Override
            public AuthenticationMechanism create(String mechanismName, FormParserFactory formParserFactory, Map<String, String> properties) {
                return new AnonymousMechanism();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then I added a file named io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension in src/main/resources/META-INF/services/ with the content: `mypackage.MyServletExtension`.

Finally, I have modified my web.xml file like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">

    <display-name>my-app</display-name>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>restricted resources</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <security-role>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>MY-AUTH</auth-method>
    </login-config>

</web-app>
```

In my pom.xml file I have those dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.undertow</groupId>
    <artifactId>undertow-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.9.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But at server startup I have this error:

```
09:40:20,192 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my-app-web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my-app-web: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link mypackage/MyServletExtension (Module "deployment.my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.my-app-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) [jboss-threads-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link mypackage/MyServletExtension (Module "deployment.my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.my-app-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:437) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:269) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:77) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:560) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:370) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.handleExtensions(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:243)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/undertow/servlet/ServletExtension
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:353) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:432) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension from [Module "deployment.my-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.my-app-ejb.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:205) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:455) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:404) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:385) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:130) [jboss-modules.jar:1.4.3.Final]
    ... 27 more
```

When I change the scope of dependencies from provided to compile, I have another exception:

```
10:08:01,387 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my-app-web: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./my-app-web: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension: Provider mypackage.MyServletExtension not a subtype
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320) [jboss-threads-2.2.0.Final.jar:2.2.0.Final]
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: io.undertow.servlet.ServletExtension: Provider mypackage.MyServletExtension not a subtype
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) [rt.jar:1.8.0_60]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.handleExtensions(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:243)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:150)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my configuration ?

Comment: Why not use JASPIC? That's the Java EE API for this and is really well supported by WildFly and much better documented. What you're now doing is using the low-level internal API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have packaged it in an ejb-jar which does not get a dependency on undertow by default.

You need to add

```
Dependencies: io.undertow.servlet io.undertow.core
```

to META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (or use jboss-deployment-structure.xml or package it in a war which gets these dependencies by default).